# Generate XML File with VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to generate an XML file with VBA code.

My goal is to alter Excel data, and then to export this data into a valid XML file. There's only one row of data and one row for the name of the tags which I want to have the data inside.

How can I run through all the data and generate an XML file?

Some sample data (My original file has more columns and data).
[image: Some sample data]

(The yellow data is my first block in XML and the green data my second block.)

Here's how the XML File should look:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<NmLoader>

<csvBeginTypeDefView handler ="TypeDefinition">
    <csvattTemplate>LW</csvattTemplate>
    <csvnameSpace>default</csvnameSpace>
    <csvname>Tires</csvname>
    <csvcontainerDomain/>
    <csvtypeParent>Wheels</csvtypeParent>
</csvBeginTypeDefView>

<csvBeginAttributeDefView handler = "AttributeDefinition">
    <csvname>TiresAT</csvname>
    <csvattDefClass>Definition</csvattDefClass>
    <csvdatatype>String</csvdatatype>
    <csvIBA>TiresAT</csvIBA>
    <csvQoM/>
</csvBeginAttributeDefView>

</NmLoader>
```

My Code:

```vb
Public Sub GenerateXML()
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim loLetzteZ As Long, loLetzteS As Long, i As Long
 Dim rBereich As Range, rng As Range
 Dim sTagO As String, sTagC As String, sTagOEnd As String, sTagCStart As String
 Dim sZeile As String
 Dim strPfad As String
 Dim strText As String
 sTagO = "<"
 sTagOEnd = "/>"
 sTagC = ">"
 sTagCStart = "</"
  
  Set sht = Worksheets("Data")
  
  'determine the last possible row
  loLetzteZ = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
  'determine the last possible column
  loLetzteS = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
  'set me the area for the complete worksheet
  Set rBereich = sht.Range("A2:" & Cells(loLetzteZ, loLetzteS).Address)
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 strPfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Data" & ".xml"
    
  'row for row
  For Each rng In rBereich.Rows
    With rng
        
        'column for column
        For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
            
              'If the tag is empty, then close this
              If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, i)) Then
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & Cells(1, i) & sTagOEnd
                             
              Else
                               
                'Opening Tag
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & Cells(1, i) & sTagC
                       
                'Data for the tags
                sZeile = sZeile & .Cells(1, i)
                            
                'End of Tags
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagCStart & Cells(1, i) & sTagC
                                
              End If
             
          'Write line with distance
          sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf
        
        Next
        'Write line with distance
        sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
        'Open file and write the text
        Call InDateiSchreiben(strPfad, sZeile, True)
    End With
 Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Other Solutions I tried:

- I've already mapped the XML with Excel, but Excel is not able to export such an XML Schema.
- I wrote code in VBA (I'm a beginner) by looking through posts regarding an XML Export.

Comment: Please provide the VBA code you wrote and someone might suggest how to make it work.

Comment: I´ve uploaded the VBA Code. The problem with the code is, it set the end tags wrong as well as the starter tag.

Comment: Data for tag should be `Cells(2, i)` as 1 has the tag name.

Comment: I suggest you step it in the debugger to see what is generated, step-by-step.

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn´t work. Now even more tags without data inside.

Comment: You tried _what_? Did you step it? (And of course inspect what happens...)

Comment: @Paul It confused me for a while but data is (dot)Cells(1, i) so relative to rng starting at A2.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateXML()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Data")

    Dim loLetzteZ As Long, loLetzteS As Long, i As Long
    Dim rBereich As Range, rng As Range
    Dim sZeile As String
    Dim strPfad As String
    Dim sTag As String, sTag1 As String, sData As String

    'determine the last possible row
    loLetzteZ = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'determine the last possible column
    loLetzteS = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'set me the area for the complete worksheet
    Set rBereich = sht.Range("A2:" & Cells(loLetzteZ, loLetzteS).Address)

    ' output
    strPfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Data" & ".xml"

    sTag1 = ""
    sZeile = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf _
    & "<NmLoader>" & vbCrLf

     'row for row
    For Each rng In rBereich.Rows
        With rng

            'column for column
            For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
                sTag = Trim(sht.Cells(1, i))
                sData = Trim(.Cells(1, i))

                'If the tag is handler
                If LCase(Right(sTag, 7)) = "handler" Then
                    
                    sTag1 = Split(sTag, " ")(0) ' remove handler
                    sZeile = sZeile & "<" & sTag1 & " handler=""" & sData & """>"
                    
                ' is it a closing tag
                ElseIf sTag = sTag1 Then
                    sZeile = sZeile & "</" & sTag1 & ">" & vbCrLf
                    
                ElseIf Len(sData) > 0 Then
                    sZeile = sZeile & vbTab & "<" & sTag & ">" & sData & "</" & sTag & ">"
                Else
                    sZeile = sZeile & vbTab & "<" & sTag & "/>"
                End If

                sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf
            Next

            'Write line with distance
            sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf & "</NmLoader>" & vbCrLf

            'Open file and write the text
            Debug.Print sZeile
            'Call InDateiSchreiben(strPfad, sZeile, True)
        End With

    Next
    MsgBox strPfad & " created", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Your code seems almost to work. There´s just one problem. The second block (green one) is created correctly. The first block (red one) still have a problem somehow. 

Here I have a problem: (Somehow the first line is creating the tag  and the data wrong and the closing tag has the / on the wrong side - The data in between is generated correctly) 
<csvBeginTypeDefView handler >TypeDefinition</csvBeginTypeDefView handler > <csvBeginTypeDefView/>

Comment: @Jacky It looks like you have a  hidden space after the word handler so I have added some Trim() statements and corrected my error in duplicating handler in the opening tag.- see update.

Comment: @Jacky See update, just noticed the last column of the block is the matching closing tag to the start of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```vb
Function GetXmlElement(sTagName As String, _
                       sValue As String, _
                       Optional bUseEmptyTags As Boolean = False, _
                       Optional bMultiline As Boolean = False) As String
    
    Dim sStartOpen As String:   sStartOpen = "<"
    Dim sClose As String:       sClose = ">"
    Dim sEndOpen As String:     sEndOpen = "</"
    Dim sEmptyClose As String:  sEmptyClose = " />"
    Dim sTab As String:         sTab = "    "
        
    Dim sTagValSeparator As String
    Dim sValTagSeparator As String
    If bMultiline Then
        sTagValSeparator = Chr(10) & sTab
        sValTagSeparator = Chr(10)
    End If
    
    If Len(sValue) = 0 And bUseEmptyTags Then
        GetXmlElement = sStartOpen & sTagName & sEmptyClose
    Else
        GetXmlElement = sStartOpen & sTagName & sClose & sTagValSeparator & _
                        Replace(sValue, Chr(10), Chr(10) & sTab) & _
                        sValTagSeparator
        
        If InStr(1, sTagName, " ") > 0 Then
            'tag has attributes'
            sTagName = Left(sTagName, InStr(1, sTagName, " ") - 1)
        End If
        
        GetXmlElement = GetXmlElement & sEndOpen & sTagName & sClose
    End If
End Function

Function GetXMLOutput() As String
    Dim lLastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCsvBeginCol As Long
    Dim sTagName As String
    Dim sInnerElements As String
    Dim sOutput As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        lLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        lCsvBeginCol = 1
        For i = 1 To lLastCol
            sTagName = .Cells(1, i)
            If Left(sTagName, 8) = "csvBegin" And i > lCsvBeginCol Or i = lLastCol Then
                ' build the outer element
                sTagName = .Cells(1, lCsvBeginCol) & "=""" & .Cells(2, lCsvBeginCol) & """"
                If Len(sOutput) > 0 Then
                    sOutput = sOutput & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
                End If
                sOutput = sOutput & GetXmlElement(sTagName, sInnerElements, True, True)
                lCsvBeginCol = i
                sInnerElements = ""
            ElseIf i <> lCsvBeginCol Then
                ' build the inner elements
                If Len(sInnerElements) > 0 Then sInnerElements = sInnerElements & Chr(10)
                sInnerElements = sInnerElements & GetXmlElement(sTagName, .Cells(2, i), True)
            End If
        Next i
        
        sOutput = GetXmlElement("NmLoader", sOutput, True, True)
        sOutput = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & sOutput
    
        GetXMLOutput = sOutput
        Debug.Print sOutput
    End With
End Function

Sub GenerateXML()
    Dim sFilename As String
    sFilename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data.xml"
    Open sFilename For Output As #1
    Print #1, GetXMLOutput
    Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]